# Running a compiled C program on a shared hosting account?

Tags: gcc, shared-hosting

Is it possible to run a compiled program on a shared hosting account?I dont think I have permission to run gcc, but I can compile it elsewhere and download it - would that work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it would work in most cases, as long as you can match system libraries / link statically.
Anyway, you will get banned eventually :-)

PS. Try VPS, it's cheap and have no such embarassing restrictions.

Comment: Interesting - thanks for the pointer Bars - but why would I get banned??

Comment: SHared hosting usually have very strict limitations. If everyone would run binaries - it would overload the server.